# MySQL get all related IDs from a table matching an array

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, relational-division

I'm facing a problem while trying to retrieve all productIDs from a table if they match all items in an array, in this case, return products only if they contain every ingredient the user searched for.

Table looks like this

```
    ID  produktID   ingredientID
    ----------------------------
    1      418           1
    2      418           2
    3      418           3
    4      416           4
    5      411           1
    6      411           5
    7      411           6
```

I join this table from a products table where the main information is stored. The aim of the query should be to retreive a productID only when all ingredientIDs match with the given array. I've tried using `WHERE ingredientID IN(1,5,6)` but it always turns out to be an OR statement, returning every ID where any of the ingredients are matched.
So for example, if I pass (1,5,6) or (5,6) the product ID 411 should be returned, but if I pass (2,5,6) it should not.

The query I tried looks like this (simplified, it's part of a 5 way join to other relations like brands and catgories)

```
SELECT productID FROM products_ingredients_mm WHERE ingredientID IN (1,5,6) GROUP BY productID
```

but the result contains 418 aswell. How do I get it to match?
I hope I was able to describe the problem in an understandable way, it's really hard for me to wrap my head around it to ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called Relational Division.

```
SELECT  produktID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ingredientID IN (1,5,6)
GROUP   BY produktID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cfe8/3)

If a unique constraint was not enforce on `ingredientID` for every `produktID`, then you need to use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  produktID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ingredientID IN (1,5,6)
GROUP   BY produktID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ingredientID) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cfe8/4)

Other Source

- [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Wow that helped a lot thank you very much for the quick response, but how would I go about including an array with ingredients that may not be in the product? So if I pass that I want 1 and 3 in the product, but definitely not 6. Can you group multiple statements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT pi.productID, p.productName
FROM products_ingredients_mm pim 
INNER JOIN products p ON pim.productID = p.productID 
WHERE ingredientID IN (1,5,6)
GROUP BY productID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredientID) = 3
```